# Will new beta versions be delivered over air when out of home country?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update, beta-seed-program

I am out of U.S. for 2 weeks and I see that 2 new beta versions of ios have dropped. I haven't received any notification. Would this be because I am not in my home/registered country? Thx.

Comment: I’ve tagged this with the beta seed program instead of the developer program. Please clarify in case that changes the answer. I’ve never heard of this being the cause, but perhaps someone wants to share their specific success or failure if it helps you.

Comment: this is for the developer beta but I suppose could be either. will try to install the public and see if that works.